# Can blat use more than one core/CPU to speed up the alignment?

Tags: sequence-alignment, software-usage, blat

I am using BLAT to align two versions of the genome of *C. elegans*. I can see in the Activity Monitor of my Mac Book Pro High Sierra that `blat` is using 100% of a CPU. However, is this programme able to use more than one core / CPU to speed up the alignment?

I cannot find such option in the help page of the tool [here](https://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/help/blatSpec.html).

I installed blat using `conda install -c bioconda blat`.

I am using the latest version of `blat`, i.e. 36.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BLAT can only use one CPU. It is actually not the right tool for full-genome alignment. For "two versions" of the same species, MUMmer and minimap2 are orders of magnitude faster and probably give better alignment.

EDIT (moving comment to answer): OP comments that the purpose of this alignment is for lifting over annotations using the UCSC PSL-based pipeline. So far there are no converters for minimap2's SAM/PAF or MUMmer's delta formats. With the UCSC pipeline, you have to write a converter by yourself. An alternative approach is to use minimap2's liftover. The [minimap2 cookbook](https://github.com/lh3/minimap2/blob/master/cookbook.md#liftover) gives an example:

```shell
minimap2 -cx asm5 --cs ecoli_ref.fa ecoli_canu.fa > ecoli_canu.paf
echo -e 'tig00000001\t200000\t300000' | paftools.js liftover ecoli_canu.paf -
```

Note that this pipeline is not as mature as UCSC liftOver and is not as scalable.

Comment: I need an alignment in PSL format for downstream tools needed for lifting over an annotation. Do you know if I can get an alignment in psl format with nucmer or minimap2?

Comment: @charlesdarwin LASTZ tool might also be worth a look for this, although it's quite old now...